# Extracting contents of <option> tags in R

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I'm trying to extract the text inside these `<option>` blocks.

What I've tried is look behinds and look aheads.

```
(?s)(?<=option value=\"\d).*?(?=<\/option)
(?s)(?<=option value=\"[0-9]).*?(?=<\/option)
```

However the value numbers change and I can't figure out how to capture multiple numbers inside a lookbehind.

Example:

`<option value="140">First string I wanna get</option>
<option value="6070">Another string I want</option>
<option value="20">This is interesting</option>`

Comment: `(?s)(?<=option value="\d+").*?(?=<\/option)` ..... in which language ? it's better to use some html parser instead

Comment: I'm parsing it in R but I don't have the source of this source code. I just have the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use xpath with an xpression like `/option` or `//option` depending on what you need.

However, if you want to use a regex, then you can use a regex with capturing group like this:

```
<option.*?>(.*?)</option>
or
<option[^>]+>(.*?)</option>
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/0UH33O/2)**

Comment: Thanks! I'd use rvest and the xpath approach if I had the website. Sadly I don't. Thanks a lot :D